# Scala accessing an element of a sorted set

Tags: scala, set, sortedset

I have a `SortedSet[Int]` object and I want to be able to find its median by retrieving `mySet(sizeOfMySet/2)`, however it only says things like true and false. Is there some other way to retrieve elements?

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val sorted = collection.immutable.SortedSet(5,3,1,7,2)
sorted: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(1, 2, 3, 5, 7)

scala> val half = sorted.size / 2
half: Int = 2

scala> val median = sorted.slice(half, half+1).headOption
median: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

If you are sure the set is nonempty (and thus don't need an `Option` to cover that case) you can just use `head`.

Comment: I just realized maybe SortedSet won't work for me because I can have repeating elements. Is there a SortedList?

Comment: @user5045023 yes. Alternately you can use a `SortedSet((Item, NumTimes))`

Comment: While this is correct, its worth noting that `slice` is going to iterate through the first `half` elements, its not going to jump to the right position.  (At least judging from the code in scala 2.11.8 -- `slice` comes from `IterableLike`, which calls (`iterator drop lo`)[https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L117]).

Comment: @ImranRashid - `SortedSet` is usually a `TreeSet` which is implemented by a `RBTree` which has an efficient `slice`.  (Not that any of this is all *that* efficient with boxed integers.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way how you can get median over a collection of objects.

```
val sorted = collection.immutable.SortedSet(5,3,1,2,4,6)
val size = sorted.size
val median = if(size%2==0){
 // if there is a pair number of items, 
 // the median is the average of the two central elements
 (sorted.take(size/2+1).range(size/2, size/2+2).sum)/2.0
}
else{
 sorted.take(size/2+1).last
}
```